# El mapa no actualiza si no cambio de ventana

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tardes y muchas gracias de antemanos.

Estoy intentando crear una web en la que aparezca en tiempo real un punto indicando mi posición.

El código del final que he creado creo que  realiza lo que espero. Pero después de probar en varios navegadores no logro llegar a una comprobación.

- Chrome: Al cargar me aparece el marcador con mi posición. Pero si me muevo, no se actualiza. Para que esto ocurra debo cambiar de pestaña del navegar y al volver si actualiza.
- Ópera y firefox: Si que actualiza sin cambiar de pestaña pero me piden continuamente los permisos de localización. Lo cual no crea una buena experiencia de usuario.
- App cordova: Simplemente no actualiza. La primera posición que tengo es la que mantiene.

Para todo esto estoy usando la API de javascript de google y los lenguajes básicos de web.

Dejo el código.

```
var map;
var marker;
var markerN;

var styles   =  [
              {
                  featureType: 'poi.business',
                  elementType: 'labels',
                  "stylers":  [
                    { "visibility": "off" }
                      ]
              }


                    ];




          function initMap(){

            //creamos un objeto styledMap utilizando la definicion anterior
            var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: "Styled Map"});

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8685452,-6.97);

            var map = new   google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                center: myLatlng,
                                zoom: 15,
                                styles: [
                                          {
                                            featureType: 'poi.business',
                                            elementType: 'labels',
                                            "stylers":  [
                                                          { "visibility": "off" }
                                                        ]
                                          }         
                                        ]
                            });

            //var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
            var image='URL donde se encuentra la imagen del punto a usar';

            var pos = {
                          lat: 38.864749,
                          lng: -6.991760
                      };

            var markerN = new   google.maps.Marker({
                                  position: pos,
                                  map: map,
                                  draggable:false,
                                  icon: image
                                });
            var timempoEn=5000;
            //window.addEventListener('load', inicio(markerN,map), false);

            //Invonco cada 5 segundo la llamada a un nuevo marcador para dar mi posición.
            setTimeout(function(){inicio()} ,timempoEn);



            $.ajax({
              type: "GET", 
              url: "URL de mi servidor",
              dataType: "text",
              success: function Marcador(data){

                  $(data).find('marker').each(function(){

                      var $marker=$(this);
                      var name=$marker.attr("name");

                      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                          parseFloat($marker.attr("lat")),
                          parseFloat($marker.attr("lng"))
                        );

                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          map: map,
                          position: point,
                          draggable:false
                    });
                  });
                }
            });

            $("#NuevoLocal").click(function(){  
                  //console.log("dsfdsfsdfsdfsdf");

                    var IntoMarck =  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

                        var posl = {
                                      lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                      lng: position.coords.longitude
                                    };

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          map: map,
                          position: posl,
                          draggable:false,
                          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                        });
                    });
                });


            function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
                  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.')
                }


          //var localizacion= navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
                function inicio(){
                  //if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    var watch_id =  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){

                      var pos = {
                                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                  lng: position.coords.longitude
                                };

                        //markerN.setMap(null);


                      markerN = new   google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: pos,
                                        map: map,
                                        draggable:false
                                        // icon: image,
                                      });                 
                      console.log("mingui");

                        //map.setCenter(pos);

                      },  function() {
                              handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                          });
                      setTimeout(function(){inicio()} ,timempoEn);

              }


          }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Es la primera vez que escribo en un foro. Espero que no se haga difícil de leer o entender y que la pregunta sea adecuada.

De nuevo gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo tu código puedo ver que intentas actualizar la posición cada 5 segundos, sin embargo estas utilizando la función `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error)` la cual genera una suscripción con el navegador y llama a la función que le pasas como primer parámetro cada que se actualiza la posición del navegador.

Aquí es donde tiene problemas tu código, ya que intentas generar una suscripción nueva cada vez que se llama tu función `inicio()`.

Para a arreglarlo, llama a la función inicio una sola vez y `watchPosition` va a ejecutar la función que le pasas como primer parámetro cada vez que la ubicación cambie.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ya lo he solucionado. Un saludo.